# How to limit Ionic app width?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm using Ionic for mobile phones and tablets.
The display on phones is gorgeous. However, on tablets, it's really too "stretched".

How to restrict width of the app, on all pages?

[image: iPad screenshot]

Comment: have you tried `left` and `right` `padding` on `ion-content` and `ion-header`?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it using the [**Ionic grid**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/). You need to give `breakpoints` according to your requirement.

*e.g.*

```
<ion-col col-sm-12 col-md-6>
        1 of 2
</ion-col>
```